# calculate quantity from shopping basket ($_SESSION['basket'];)

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a shopping cart for the past few months and this has always been a problem that I just can't get solved. I have looked up different shopping carts online that are session based. tried what they did but this only results to having only 1 item updating every time. I have asked my friends if they see what is going wrong and they can't find it either. So does anyone know how to update quantity along side the item that the user wants to update from the cart??

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errrors', '1');
// session_destroy();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Cart</title>
        <!-- Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Bootstrap icons-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/stylecart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/scripts.js" async></script>

    </head>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }

    </style>

<body>
<!--navbar-->
<a class="back" href="index.php"> <i class="bi bi-arrow-left-circle-fill bi-5x"></i></a>
<?php 
include "config.php";
        ?>
        <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 100px;">&#128717;</div>
        <h2 class="text-center">Winkelmandje</h2><br>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <!-- <h2 class="section-header">CART</h2> -->
            <div class="cart-row">
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>   
                <!-- <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">berekening</span>   -->
                <!-- <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">Verwijderen</span>  -->
            </div>  
            <?php
            
            if (isset($_SESSION['basket'])){
                if( in_array(  $_GET['broodjes_ID'] ,$_SESSION['basket']) )
                {
                    
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['basket'][] = $_GET['broodjes_ID'];
                   
                    
                }
            }else{
                $_SESSION['basket'][]=  $_GET['broodjes_ID'];
            }

            
            $sumtotal = 0;
           
                     foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $key => $value){
                         //print_r(array_keys($_SESSION['basket']));
                         //echo "Key = $key; value = $value; <br>";
                         $sql = "SELECT * FROM broodjes WHERE broodjes_ID=?";
                         $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                         $stmt->bind_param("i", $value);
                         $stmt->execute();
                         $result = $stmt->get_result();
                        
                         if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                            
                     
                            echo '<div class="cart-items">';
                            echo '<div class="cart-row">';
                                echo '<div class="cart-item cart-column">';
                                    echo $row['broodnaam'];
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '<div class="cart-item cart-column">';
                                    echo '€ ' . $row['prijs'];
                                echo '</div>';
                                //quantity
                                echo '<div class="cart-item cart-column">';
                                
                                  echo '<form action="" method="POST">';
                                     echo '<div class="col-xs-4">';
                                     echo '<input type="hidden" name="broodnaam" id="broodnaam" value="' . $row['broodnaam'] . '">';
                                     echo '<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control input-sm" value="1" min="1" max="'.$row['voorraad'].'">';
                                     echo '</div>';
                                  echo '</form>';
                                 echo '</div>';
                       
                                $_SESSION['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
                                if ($_POST['broodnaam'] == $_POST['quantity']){
                                    $rowtotaal = $row['prijs'] * $_SESSION['quantity'];
                                    $sumtotal += $rowtotaal;
                                }else{
                                    $rowtotaal = $row['prijs'] * 1;
                                    $sumtotal += $rowtotaal;
                                }
                                

                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '</div>';

                          
                         }
                         
                        
                     } 
                     ?> <br />
               
                    <div class="cart-total">
                        <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                        <span class="cart-total-price"> € <?php   echo $sumtotal;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                     
                
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><a href="bestellen.php"> bestellen</a></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete"><a href="deleteeverything.php"> empty cart</a></button>
                   
            
             <br>
           <br />
        </section>
    </body>
```

mysqli table broodjes (maybe this helps)

[image]

Comment: blindly assigning `$broodjes = $_GET['broodjes_ID'];` may well cause errors. ID attributes in HTML *must* be unique. What is `broodnaam`? Why the nest `select` queries - a single query could fetch all the records which would be more efficient.

Comment: broodnaam = breadname aka the name of the bread. I fixed the query to SELECT * FROM broodjes WHERE broodjes_ID =? not sure why $broodjes = $_GET['broodjed_ID'] would cause errors but right now I removed that line and replaced every $broodjes with $_GET['broodjes_ID']

Comment: If there was no querystring or no `broodjes_ID` in the querystring it would cause an error - undefined index.

Comment: oh that's what you mean but it has that my link looks like this for example http://localhost/bestelapp/cart.php?broodjes_ID=52 andx I'm not getting that error at all

Comment: You should test that the expected parameters are set within either the GET or POST request ( or other ) before trying to assign them to variables to avoid errors. You might, inadvertently, reveal more about your application than you should by not doing so - especially if all errors are printed in full.

Comment: It would be very useful to others if you could provide a `var_dump` or other nicely formatted representation of the session variable variables involved. It is curious that you have a separate session variable for `quantity` - surely the session `basket` should be structured so that each product added includes it's own ID and quantity... ???!!!